# How to traverse thru a response when it is as below

Tags: karate

```
{
    "createDate": "2019-05-15 10:07:44",
    "mak": "pokijoklm",
    "optStatus": "yujuim",
    "partnerAccount": {
        "operatorName": "frftcrtii",
        "partnerCustomerId": "XXXXX",
        "type": "partnerAccount"
    },
    "transactionId": "hjknhijn1",
    "type": "nihnui",
    "updateDate": "2019-05-15 11:20:59"
}
```

For an array we can try as response.partneraccount[*]. but my response is { }

Comment: `response.partneraccount` is not an array, so you cannot access it as such.  Simply retrieving `response.partneraccount` rather than `response.partneraccount[*]` will get you the object inside that key, and you can access it as any other object.

Comment: response.partnerAccount.partnerCustomerId i tried this way. this is not working.

Comment: what is returned when you do `console.log(response)`

Comment: Im new to karate framework, console.log does not work.

Comment: my apologies, i thought this was a javascript related question

Answer (score 1):

You use `[]` only when there are arrays. Just observe your JSON structure carefully and you will get it. Try pasting the below into a fresh `Scenario` and see it work:

```
* def response =
"""
{
    "createDate": "2019-05-15 10:07:44",
    "mak": "pokijoklm",
    "optStatus": "yujuim",
    "partnerAccount": {
        "operatorName": "frftcrtii",
        "partnerCustomerId": "XXXXX",
        "type": "partnerAccount"
    },
    "transactionId": "hjknhijn1",
    "type": "nihnui",
    "updateDate": "2019-05-15 11:20:59"
}
"""
* def partnerAccount = response.partnerAccount
* match partnerAccount == { operatorName: 'frftcrtii', partnerCustomerId: 'XXXXX',  type: 'partnerAccount' }
* def custId = response.partnerAccount.partnerCustomerId
* match custId == 'XXXXX'
```

Comment: This is like we are hard-coding a response value and matching the customerId value.  is it possible to take value from response and assert the custid ?  like the print opt status value which is as below . Then status 200
    * def optStatus = response.optStatus
    * print ' optStatus :' + optStatus

Comment: @AJs the above is just an example, in a real test the `response` variable will contain the *actual* response. I am showing you the above trick because it will save time - you just paste the response and you can re-test your `match` assertions without wasting time waiting for the server to respond